# Getting contacts from Outlook no matter the version

Tags: c#, import, outlook, export, contacts

I have been working on this problem for a while now.
I can get the contacts from Outlook 2013, but when running it for Outlook 2010 nothing happens.

My guess is that my reference is Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library. I tried installing Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library in order to use this a reference as well. But that doesn't work either.

So my question is, is there really no way that i can work with contacts from Outlook no matter what version is installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the interop from the lowest supported version of Outlook - all Outlook versions are backward compatible.

Comment: That actually makes perfect sense. The only thing I need to know now is how I add the Outlook 2010 in the reference list? I installed o2010pia.msi, and I see Microsoft Office 2010 Primary Interop Assemblies in "Programs and functions" but I don't see it in Visual Studio References.

Comment: If you have the interop dll, you can add it directly as a reference instead of adding a reference to Outlook from the COM tab.

Comment: Do you have any idea where I find the .dll? :/

Comment: You can create it on a machine where Outlook 2010 is installed.

Comment: Okay. And after doing that I figured out that it didn't work with the 2013. Am I missing something or is it really a pain in the ...?

Comment: "Did not work" in what sense? Did you get an error? What is it? Did you make sure "version specific" reference for the interop is set to false?